# Splitting the mean in the (Backward) Fokker-Planck

Tags: stochastic-processes, soft-matter

A method for deriving the Fokker-Planck equation is outlined below$^1$ (I believe it is a simplified version of the Kramers-Moyal expansion).

> 1. Set:
>      $$P(\vec x, t+\Delta t) =\left<\delta(\vec r(t+\Delta t)-\vec x) \right>$$
> 2. We write $\vec r(t+\Delta t)=\vec r+\Delta \vec r$ and expand the Dirac delta function:
>      $$ P(\vec x, t+\Delta t) =\left<\delta(\vec r(t)-\vec x)-\Delta  r_i \partial_i \delta(\vec r(t)-\vec x)+\frac{1}{2} \Delta r_i \Delta r_j \partial_i \partial_j\delta(\vec r(t)-\vec x)+\ldots  \right>$$
>      All derivatives here are with respect to $\vec x$ (hence the minus sign in front of the first order term).
> 3. We then do the following:
>      $$\left<\Delta  r_i \partial_i \delta(\vec r(t)-\vec x)\right>=\partial_i \left<\Delta r_i \right> \left<\delta(\vec r(t)-\vec x)\right>\tag{1}$$
>      and analogous with the second order term
> 4. To then get to the Fokker-Planck equation we find $\left< \Delta r_i\right>$ and $\left< \Delta r_i \Delta r_j \right>$ from the Langevin equation.

A similar method can be used to derive the backward Fokker-Planck equation:

> 1. Set: $$P(\vec x, t|\vec x_0, t_0-\Delta t_0)
>     =\left<\delta(\vec r(t|x_0,t_0-\Delta t_0)-\vec x) \right>$$
> 2. We write $\vec r(t|x_0,t_0-\Delta t_0)=\vec r(t|x_0+\Delta r_0,t_0)$
>      and expand the dirac delta function: $$P(\vec x, t|\vec x_0,
>     t_0-\Delta t_0) =\left<\delta(\vec r(t|x_0,t_0)-\vec x)+\Delta r_0^i
>     \partial_i\delta(\vec r(t|x_0,t_0)-\vec x) +\frac{1}{2} \Delta r_0^i 
>     \Delta r_0^j \partial_i\partial_j\delta(\vec r(t|x_0,t_0)-\vec
>     x)+\ldots\right>$$
>   All derivatives here are with respect to $\vec
>    x_0$.
> 3. We then do the following: $$\left<\Delta r_0^i
>     \partial_i\delta(\vec r(t|x_0,t_0)-\vec x)\right>= \left<\Delta r_0^i
>     \right> \partial_i\left<\delta(\vec r(t|x_0,t_0)-\vec
>     x)\right>\tag{2}$$ and analogous with the second order term
> 4. To then get to the Fokker-Planck equation we find $\left< \Delta
>     r_0^i\right>$ and $\left< \Delta r_0^i \Delta r_0^j \right>$ from the
>      Langevin equation.

I understand these derivations except the equations (1) and (2). For the Forward FP equation we split the mean within the derivative whilst for the backward FP we split it outside. How can these two equations be justified on physical grounds (i.e. in terms of the noise present)? And why in one of them are we allowed to split a displacement and the delta function whilst in the other a displacement and the derivative of a delta function.

I note that such reasoning is not required for the  full Kramers-Moyal expansion and only in this simplified version - which my question is focusing on.

<sub>$^1$ I don't have a publicly available source for this but will try and find one.</sub>

Comment: Actually, to derive FP equations you just need the Kramers-Moyal expansion and Pawula's theorem, which states that either the KM expansion stops after 2 terms or is infinite. Then, I believe you get a FP equation for the system under study only if the 3rd coefficient in KM is zero, and the 2 first are non-zero. NB: I can't find any proof in a publicly available material, but I can provide the proof if needed

Comment: @Naptzer I am aware that it can be derived by the Kramers-Moyal expansion but am specifically interested in understanding the derivations presented in my question. Although thanks for informing me about Pawula's theorem - this is something I did not know.

Comment: No source yet ? I feel like there is an issue with both (1) and (2), as I don't see how to take the terms needed for these relations to hold out of the integral (ensemble average) of the LHS. Plus, I read a similar derivation just now, but they made use of the fact that the probability was $v$ dependent ($P(v,t)$ instead of $P(x,t)$), to make the splitting. More on that when I understand better and have time to write a full comment.